# Androidのレシーバーの処理について

Tags: android

初歩的な質問ですみません。

Androidでalarm managerでreceiverを呼び出し
receiverでpending intentを呼ぶとします

この時、自分自身つまりアプリが起動中だった時、
pending intentで呼ばれたアクティビティは新規のアクティビティになりますか？

logcatでみるとremoteって項目ができてて。。

出来ればアプリ起動中なら、起動中のアプリのアクティビティははを呼びたいです。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://techbooster.org/android/application/2166/
こちらのブログのような実装になると思うのですが、Intentにフラグを設定すれば行けるかと思います。
※ただし未検証です

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReceivedActivity.class);
intent.setFalgs(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
```

状況のよっては別のフラグが最適かもしれません。
下記のブログが参考になると思います。

※フラグについて
http://androidroid.info/android/activity/568/